# How to transfer JS array to external script

Tags: javascript, arrays, smarty

How can I transfer JS array to external script?
I have smarty array {myarray} and this code:

```
<li onclick='myfunction("{myarray}")'>TRANSFER</li>
```

externalscript.js looks:

```
function myfunction(myarray)
{
    var content = '<table class="table-data-sheet" id="table">';
    {foreach $myarray key=k item=f}
    content +='<tr>';
    content += '<td>' + "{$k}" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "{$f}" + '</td>';
    content += '</tr>';
    {/foreach}
    content += '</table>';
    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = content;
}
```

But its not working. I don't know why. 
I can transfer variable but not array.

Comment: it seems like you are sending a plain string, "{myarray}", have you tried without the double quotes and just sending {myarray}?

Answer (score 0):

you could json_encode the array

```
<li onclick="myfunction({$myarray|@json_encode nofilter})">Transfer</li>
```

and use it as object in JS

```
function myfunction(myObj) {
    var tableElement = document.createElement('table');
    tableElement.id = 'tableid';
    tableElement.className = 'table-data-sheet';
    var content = '';
    var valueKeys = Object.keys(myObj);
    for(var i=0;i<valueKeys.length;i++){
        content +='<tr><td>'+valueKeys[i]+'</td><td>'+myObj[valueKeys[i]]+'</td></tr>';
    }
    tableElement.innerHTML = content;
    document.getElementById("tabledivid").appendChild(tableElement);
}
```

if you would have an array of values and not a key value construct, you could maybe do this

```
implode(', ', $fruit)
```

and use the arguments object in JS

```
function myfunction() {
    var tableElement = document.createElement('table');
    tableElement.id = 'tableid';
    tableElement.className = 'table-data-sheet';
    var content = '';
    for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
        content +='<tr><td>'+i+'</td><td>'+arguments[i]+'</td></tr>';
    }
    tableElement.innerHTML = content;
    document.getElementById("tabledivid").appendChild(tableElement);
}
```